# Ubuntu automated installation

Tags: software-installation

I have 30 systems(same configuration) to install Ubuntu 17. Is there any option to setup the installation automated like WDS in windows. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

For my systems at home, I use netboot installs. This allows you to run the installer from the bare metal and install a stock system with whatever parameters and packages you require. It does require some setup (dhcp server, tftp server, and preseed files), but mine go without intervention from nothing to full install. I just have to go in and set passwords when I'm done. I could even skip that but that works for me.

I started from here and heavily modified: https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/05/20/fully-automated-ubuntu-install/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. For posterity, I would suggest the following:

- Search how to backup and migrate all packages and configurations from one current system to another (new) system. *rsync* is good and reliable, but there are other packages such as **aptik**.
- Check out the forks of *remastersys* such as [Pengy Builder](https://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/) or [Ubuntu Imager](https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager)
- I believe the easiest of these all is Penguy Builder, but I am not certain of your exact needs.